# XAMPP MySQL stop running query

Tags: mysql

in a past few days, I have a problem with my XAMPP (v3.2.2). The problem is that MySQL randomly stops running a query in PHP. Then I need to restart MySQL from XAMPP console and it is working again. There is no error in XAMPP console. I can see the page (i guess that Apache is working) but when I run for example some search query in PHP I won't show result until I restart MySQL in XAMPP.

I check file 'mysql_error.log in XAMPP\mysql\data and it is 2GB big. When I open it I noticed that I am getting the same error:

`2018-06-12 11:11:57 4696 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma_usergroups in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 7, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.`

This repeat with other tables also.

I am a beginner at using XAMPP so please can you suggest how to find what is causing the problem.

Comment: MySQL claims that you removed a number of its files.  If that really is the case, you can't expect it to run smoothly.